# Automatically parse line of Dataframe extracted from Json

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I wrote a script that parses a Json file into a dataframe.
this is the result:

```
>> df

                           parcelles
0     {'code': '680CC68A-D4A9-4E24-AC66-F1186A9A4BBC...
1     {'code': 'DDA7E136-E21E-474B-95E2-F42E5D794AEF...
2     {'code': 'DF9F311D-9620-4755-A43F-F7CB839B428E...
3     {'code': '98D7BDEA-5696-42D0-B2AC-3B47782D64FE...
4     {'code': '83B6B9D0-3EDF-420B-9A20-BFF27187201A...
5     {'code': '698CD222-5090-4017-8361-E4154B371B99...


>> df['parcelles'][0]

{'code': '680CC68A-D4A9-4E24-AC66-F1186A9A4BBC',
 'nomUsuel': '9816 02  LES FLORANCIS',
 'numero': 'VT 77CHT9617',
 'campagne': {'code': None},
 'cru': {'code': None, 'libelle': None}
}
```

Is there anyway to automatically parse each line of the DF ( `df['parcelles'][0]` ). I want to have something like this:

```
for Some in Something:
    print(Some + " value is: " + (df['parcelles'][0][Some]) +"\n" )
```

The result would be:

```
code value is: 680CC68A-D4A9-4E24-AC66-F1186A9A4BBC
nomUsuel value is: 9816 02  LES FLORANCIS
numero value is: VT 77CHT9617
....
```

I am already able to get all of the values with: `df['parcelles'][0]['code']` so I only need a method to replace `code` by all of the json key values. Ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [the solution](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/iterate-over-a-dictionary-in-python/). The result of `df['parcelles'][0]` has `dict` type. To parse it, we can do:

```
for a in df['parcelles'][0]:
    print(str(a) +" value is: "+str(df['parcelles'][0][a])+"\n")
```